# Notepad++ find and add a string with available information

Tags: notepad++, regex

Using Notepad++ I have the following text:

```
abc 123123
genre: test 1, test 2, test 3
```

I want it to become:

```
abc 123123
genre: test 1, test 2, test 3
<tag>test 1, test 2, test 3</tag>
```

"test 1, test 2, test 3" are always changing, but it's always in one line and after "genre:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what: `genre: (.+)`
Replace with: `genre: \1\r\n<tag>\1</tag>`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.